# Why python does not raise NameError

Tags: python, python-2.7

Consider this simple case:

```
i = 10
if i != id:
    print i
```

As `id` is not defined here so i was assuming to get `NameError: name 'id' is not defined` but it does not raise any.

But in this case:

```
id = 10
if i != id:
    print i
```

It actually raised a `NameError` exception for `i`. So can anyone explain it to me this behaviour?

Comment: `id` is a [built-in function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`id` is a built-in function, so it actually is defined. Use another name for your variable.

Here is a list of all [built-in functions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html).

Comment: Sorry my bad. It just didn't came into my mind that it can be a built-in function name.

Comment: i will as soon as 15 minutes are passed.

Comment: Oops, forgot about that. My bad now. :)